# How to sum values of certain properties for each subgroup nested array object's in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

From the object below, I wanted to sum up certain properties (fare+tax and com+agency) by their key group (1345, 2353) and updated it in the current array object.

```
var details = [{ 1345:[
                {route: 34, fare: 45, tax: 46, date: 46, com: 45, agency: 24, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}], 
               2353: [
                {route: 32, fare: 45, tax: 45, date: 56, com: 34, agency: 52, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}, 
                {route: 42, fare: 34, tax: 64, date: 34, com: 56, agency: 34, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}
              ]} 
             ]
```

expected output: updated `details` (totalCost and totalFee)

```
    1345: 
{ route: 34, fare: 45, .... totalCost: 91, totalFee: 69 }
    2353: 
{ route: 32, fare: 45, ... totalCost: 188, totalFee: 90 },
{ route: 42, fare: 34, ... totalCost: 188, totalFee: 176 }
```

`totalCost = fare + tax` and `totalFee = com + agency`

I tried to simplified the array objects and convert by using Object.entries(details[0]), then reduce to sum up the target properties.

```
Object.entries(details[0]).reduce((acc, curr) => (acc = acc + curr["fare"]+curr["tax"]), 0);
```

However, NaN was returned.

Would appreciate if anyone could show me how I can loop through each key group and sum up the target values and update it (totalCost and totalFee).

Comment: You should use `Object.values` instead of `Object.entries`, and also you don't need to assign a new value to `acc`.

Comment: Pretty sure that `totalFee` on 2353 is wrong (34 + 52 + 56 + 34) !== 90

Comment: @kelly I tried changing Object.entries to .values and remove acc, but it still doesn't work. If possible, can you give me an example? **I have updated my question and expected output. Thanks alot!

Comment: @benbotto you're right! I was in a hurried and didn't realized that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (of many) would be to use a simple sum function to sum up an arbitrary array of values:

```
function sum(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val)
}
```

Next, sum up the `totalCost`/`totalFee` logic for each key group (1345 and 2353), and then apply the sums to each array entry:

```
for (const [key, vals] of Object.entries(details[0])) {
  vals.forEach((val, _, vals) => {
    val.totalFee  = sum(...vals.map(val => val.com + val.agency))
    val.totalCost = sum(...vals.map(val => val.fare + val.tax))
  })
}
```

Here's the whole shebang:

```js
const details = [
  {
    1345: [
      {route: 34, fare: 45, tax: 46, date: 46, com: 45, agency: 24, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0},
    ], 
    2353: [
      {route: 32, fare: 45, tax: 45, date: 56, com: 34, agency: 52, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}, 
      {route: 42, fare: 34, tax: 64, date: 34, com: 56, agency: 34, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0},
    ],
  },
]

for (const [key, vals] of Object.entries(details[0])) {
  vals.forEach((val, _, vals) => {
    val.totalFee  = sum(...vals.map(val => val.com + val.agency))
    val.totalCost = sum(...vals.map(val => val.fare + val.tax))
  })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(details, null, 2))

function sum(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I just wanted to update the current array object 'details' (totalCost and totalFee) or create new object with the same properties structure as 'details' , how should I modified the function ? **Each keygroup(1345, 2353) contains multiple objects.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: @hans1125 I've updated the code per your comment.  Now the two totals are updated in the original `details` object.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using a few [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) calls, the end result should be as required.

For each key group, we'd use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key and value for the group.

```js
const details = [{ 1345:[ {route: 34, fare: 45, tax: 46, date: 46, com: 45, agency: 24, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}], 2353: [ {route: 32, fare: 45, tax: 45, date: 56, com: 34, agency: 52, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}, {route: 42, fare: 34, tax: 64, date: 34, com: 56, agency: 34, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0} ]} ]
         
const result = details.reduce((acc, group) => { 
    return Object.entries(group).reduce((acc, [key, routes] ) => {
        return routes.reduce((acc, { fare, tax, com, agency}) => { 
            acc[key] = acc[key] || {};
            acc[key].totalCost = (acc[key].totalCost || 0) + fare + tax;
            acc[key].totalFee = (acc[key].totalFee || 0) + com + agency;
            return acc;
        }, acc)
    }, acc)
}, {})

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I've updated here to include the original array under each key group, naming it 'routes', this could be changed to anything:

```js
const details = [{ 1345:[ {route: 34, fare: 45, tax: 46, date: 46, com: 45, agency: 24, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}], 2353: [ {route: 32, fare: 45, tax: 45, date: 56, com: 34, agency: 52, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}, {route: 42, fare: 34, tax: 64, date: 34, com: 56, agency: 34, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0} ]} ]

const result = details.reduce((acc, group) => { 
    return Object.entries(group).reduce((acc, [key, routes] ) => {
        return routes.reduce((acc, { fare, tax, com, agency}) => { 
            acc[key] = acc[key] || { routes };
            acc[key].totalCost = (acc[key].totalCost || 0) + fare + tax;
            acc[key].totalFee = (acc[key].totalFee || 0) + com + agency;
            return acc;
        }, acc)
    }, acc)
}, {})

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks you! If I just wanted to update the current array object 'details' (totalCost and totalFee) or create new object with the same properties structure as 'details', how should I modified the function ? **Each keygroup(1345, 2353) contains multiple objects. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I've added another snippet to include the array under each key group as 'routes'. You could call this something else of course!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the use of `Object.values`

```js
var details = [{ 1345:[
                {route: 34, fare: 45, tax: 46, date: 46, com: 45, agency: 24, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}], 
               2353: [
                {route: 32, fare: 45, tax: 45, date: 56, com: 34, agency: 52, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}, 
                {route: 42, fare: 34, tax: 64, date: 34, com: 56, agency: 34, totalCost: 0, totalFee: 0}
              ]} 
             ]

Object.values(details).map(x => {
  details = {}
  let count = 0;
  for (let y of Object.values(x)) {
    y = y.reduce(function (a, b) {
      for (const key in b) {
        if (a[key]) {
          a[key] = a[key] + b[key]
        } else {
          a[key] = b[key];
        }
      }
      return a;
    }, {});
    y['totalCost'] = y['fare'] + y['tax']; 
    y['totalFee'] = y['com'] + y['agency'];
    let totalObj = {};
    totalObj['totalCost:'] = y['totalCost'];
    totalObj['totalFee:'] = y['totalFee'];
    details[`${Object.keys(x)[count]}`] = totalObj;
    count++;
  };
});

console.log(details);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! If I just wanted to update the current array object 'details' (totalCost and totalFee) or create new object with the same properties structure as 'details', how should I modified the function ? **Each keygroup(1345, 2353) contains multiple objects like in 'details'. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: That's a difficult one because you can have multiple objects in one key group - so would you want to add totalCost and totalFee to all details elements? If so that appears a bit counterintuitive since the totalCost and totalFee will not look as if they've been summed correctly.